# How do I create a loop within my selenium python script to select every option within a dropdown menu

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, webdriver, python

Im new to python, or coding for that matter... Currently I have a python script to select one option within the dropdown menu, but I would like my script to repeat each time and select the next option. Theres about 50 different options within the dropdown.

```
l1  = "Hong Kong, China (Chrome, Canary, Firefox)"

urlTextBox          = "url"
dropdownOption      = "location"
submitBtn           = ".//*[@id='start_test-container']/p/input"
homeBtn             = ".//*[@id='nav']/li[1]/a"

urlTextBoxElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
    until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(urlTextBox))

dropdownOptionElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
    until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(dropdownOption))

submitBtnElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
    until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(submitBtn))

urlTextBoxElement.send_keys(webTeamPage)
Select(dropdownOptionElement).select_by_visible_text(l1)
submitBtnElement.click()
time.sleep(3)
homeBtnElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
    until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(homeBtn))
```

Comment: IIUC you want to have script which will loop through the options, and provide results (one option text at a time) to another script which would perform some actions/checks with provided option?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to answer my own question, Please see script below:

```
    urlTextBox          = "url"
    dropdownOption      = "location"
    submitBtn           = ".//*[@id='start_test-container']/p/input"
    homeBtn             = ".//*[@id='nav']/li[1]/a"
    webTeamPage = "personalwebpage.com"


    select = driver.find_element_by_id(dropdownOption)  #get the select element
    options = select.find_elements_by_tag_name("option") #get all the options into a list
    optionsList = []

    for option in options: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list

        optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))


    for optionValue in optionsList:

        urlTextBoxElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
            until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(urlTextBox))

        dropdownOptionElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
            until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_id(dropdownOption))

        submitBtnElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
            until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(submitBtn))

        driver.find_element_by_id(urlTextBox).clear()
        urlTextBoxElement.send_keys(webTeamPage)
        submitBtnElement.click()
        time.sleep(3)
        homeBtnElement = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).\
        until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath(homeBtn))
        homeBtnElement.click()
        print "starting loop on option %s" % optionValue


        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id(dropdownOption))
        select.select_by_value(optionValue)
```